# How to structure unstructured data using apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file containing the following line:

```
3124,"hello...",ku4
3125,"hello,hi",ab2
```

I want to load the file such that it has three columns. I used `PigStorage(',')` but it is also splitting `"hello,hi"` into two. I want it under a single field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried CSVExcelStorage? 
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html

Comment: Is your no. of column same always ? Means there is always 3 field in a one tuple?

Comment: If your field is same for all tuple then you can use regular expression method for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own custom UDF or use CSVLoader from piggybank.jar

```
-- Get piggybank.jar that is compatible with your pig version and register 
   it in your pig script by pointing to the location of the jar file

REGISTER piggybank.jar

A = LOAD 'test.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader(',') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray,f3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1, f2, f3;
DUMP B;
```